# If exceptions occured turn to Try block

Tags: java, try-catch

I have problem with try catch in Java

```
 private void Bağlan_ButonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       String user=Uname_Textfield.getText();
       String pwd= new String (Password_PasswordField.getPassword());
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.131.10;" + "databaseName=Digitalk;" + "user=" + user + ";" + "password=" + pwd + ";";      
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Yanlış!");   
        } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }
    new ProgramPenceresi().setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    }
```

I have above code for Button action in loginscreen.java class. If sqlexception occurs I have already catch it and display a warning message to user. When user click OK, `ProgramPenceresi.java` coming to screen.

I want if SqlExceptions occurs to display message and when user click OK turn to loginscreen again. If sqlexceptions not occurred `ProgramPenceresi.java` can be called.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those calls inside the try/catch block:

```
   private void Bağlan_ButonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String user=Uname_Textfield.getText();
        String pwd= new String (Password_PasswordField.getPassword());
        try {  
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.131.10;" + "databaseName=Digitalk;" + "user=" + user + ";" + "password=" + pwd + ";";      
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            new ProgramPenceresi().setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Yanlış!");   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
                System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
        }
    }
```

I don't like this code at all.  There's no layering at all.  You shouldn't have UI and database code mingled this way.  You should externalize database parameters.  You shouldn't have exceptions driving logic this way.  You need to at least attempt MVC separation.

That Connection you just went to the trouble of opening will do you no good at all.  It's local to the method, so when you exit the method it'll be eligible for garbage collection.   You don't use it to make any SQL calls in the code you posted, so unless you add them later it'll be wasted.

Use it or lose it.

Don't print simple messages to System.out from catch block.  Print or log the entire stack trace.  It gives you a lot more information than your message; you'll find it's easier to debug from a full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: This button in Loginscreen. I have only validate true DB user with this screen. Other Sql queries or components calling if try block succesfull via ProgramPenceresi.java